# How to handle a miss with regex / PHP / preg_match_all

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the code at the bottom to grab parameters from a wordpress shortcode.  The shortcode itself looks like this:

```
[FLOWPLAYER=http://www.tvovermind.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/pll-316-21.jpg|http://www.tvovermind.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/PLL316_fv2.h264HD-Clip2.flv,440,280]
```

Or

```
[FLOWPLAYER=http://www.tvovermind.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/pll-316-21.jpg|http://www.tvovermind.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/PLL316_fv2.h264HD-Clip2.flv,440,280,false]
```

What I would like to have happen is that if the extra parameter (false/true) is missing then that match becomes "false",  however with the current code if the parameter is missing a match is never made.   Any ideas?

```
function legacy_hook($content){
    $regex = '/\[FLOWPLAYER=([a-z0-9\:\.\-\&\_\/\|]+)\,([0-9]+)\,([0-9]+)\,([a-z0-9\:\.\-\&\_\/\|]+)\]/i';
        $matches = array();
    preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches);
    if($matches[0][0] != '') {
        foreach($matches[0] as $key => $data) {
            $content = str_replace($matches[0][$key], flowplayer::build_player($matches[2][$key], $matches[3][$key], $matches[1][$key],$matches[4][$key]),$content);
        }   
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your regex is looking for the last comma to be there and one or more of the characters in the last set of brackets. Something like

`/\[FLOWPLAYER=([a-z0-9\:\.\-\&\_\/\|]+)\,([0-9]+)\,([0-9]+)(\,[a-z]+)?\]/i`

only issue is you'll get the comma in the match too.

might be what you're after, then you have to test for the last match being present. preg_match_all returns the number of matches so you might be able to use that, or you could do an inline if...

`(count($matches) > 4 ? $matches[4][$key] : false)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add OR at the end of your expression

```
(,true|,false|$)
```

I didn't check does it work but you get the idea.